# RELAX NG Multiple names for the element with the same structure

Tags: xml, relaxng

Suppose I have two these rules:

```
JFalse = element JFalse {
   attribute label { xs:string }?,
   attribute jump { xs:string }?,
   attribute offset { xs:integer }?
}

JGt = element JGt {
   attribute label { xs:string }?,
   attribute jump { xs:string }?,
   attribute offset { xs:integer }?
}
```

(quite a lot more in actuality)

What I'd like to do is obviously something like:

```
JFalseOrJGt = element (JFalse | JGt) {
   attribute label { xs:string }?,
   attribute jump { xs:string }?,
   attribute offset { xs:integer }?
}
```

(but the above is not valid). Can I do it in some other way, that will result in a more "compressed" grammar rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one option:

```
JFalse = element JFalse { jFalseGt }

JGt = element JGt { jFalseGt }

jFalseGt = 
   attribute label { xs:string }?,
   attribute jump { xs:string }?,
   attribute offset { xs:integer }?
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `element (JFalse | JGt)` is actually the correct syntax for declaring an element which can have either of the two names. When converting from the compact syntax to the XML syntax, `trang` converts it to:

`<element>
  <choice>
    <name>JFalse</name>
    <name>JGt</name>
  </choice>
  [...]`

which is exactly what you are asking for.

There is a bug in your code but it is unrelated to naming elements. The problem is that all of your `xs:...` types cannot be resolved. You have two choices: either you add `datatypes xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"` at the start of your file to declare the `xs` prefix, or you edit each type to use the `xsd` prefix instead of `xs`. The `xsd` prefix is declared by default.